# Why are Julia's Union and Tuple instances of DataType and not UnionAll?

Tags: types, julia

I was reading about [Julia Types](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/types/) and was trying to get a handle of the types of parametric types.

It appeared that for a parametric type itself, that is, the type without any instantiated type parameters, the type of the type was `UnionAll`, but for non-parametric types, whether instantiated from a parametric type or simply non-parametric to begin with, the type was an instance of `DataType`. Initial experiments seem to show that rule was okay:

```
julia> typeof(Int64)
DataType

julia> typeof(Symbol)
DataType

julia> typeof(Array)
UnionAll

julia> typeof(Array{Int, 2})
DataType

julia> typeof(Set)
UnionAll

julia> typeof(Set{Bool})
DataType

julia> typeof(Irrational)
UnionAll

julia> typeof(Irrational{π})
DataType

julia> typeof(DataType)
DataType

julia> typeof(UnitRange)
UnionAll

julia> typeof(UnitRange{UInt8})
DataType

julia> typeof(Dict)
UnionAll

julia> typeof(Dict{String, Int32})
DataType
```

I know that a few examples don't prove a point, but this kind of made sense based of the documentation for `UnionAll`:

> ... cannot be a normal data type, since without knowing the type of the referenced data the type clearly cannot be used for memory operations. The answer is that Ptr (or other parametric types like Array) is a different kind of type called a UnionAll type. Such a type expresses the iterated union of types for all values of some parameter.

However, there are some parametric types that are not instances of `UnionAll`  and I do not understand why. For example:

```
julia> typeof(Union)
DataType

julia> typeof(Union{Int64, Bool, Char})
Union

julia> typeof(Tuple)
DataType

julia> typeof(Tuple{Bool, Char})
DataType
```

Why are the "raw" `Union` and `Tuple` types instances of `DataType`? Other parameterized type are not. Perhaps there's something about the fact that they each take a variable number of type parameters?

Comment: For Unions, perhaps the fact that `Union{Int, Char} <: Union` is `false` explains it - `Union` is not a union-of-all-its-parametrisations, the type relations don't work out that way. But with Tuples, `Tuple{Int, Char} <: Tuple` is `true`, so I'm stumped there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer for `Tuple` is that it is unique among julia types in that it is covariant rather than invariant. (also the variable number of type parameters).

For `Union`, it's important to realize that `Union`s are representations of sets of types, not types themselves. Specifically, `Union{A,B}===Union{B,A}` so although the parameters of a `Union` look like type parameters in syntax, they are fairly fundamentally different.

Comment: Makes me wonder why `Union` is a `DataType` instead of being a keyword.

Comment: I think part of the answer here is history. Julia's type system was repeatedly refined in the pre 1.0 days, and a lot of the current status is based around what works rather than necesarily what would be optimal. (for an example of this, subtyping is turing complete which isn't exactly ideal).